# Getting wrong date in primefaces schedule on event eventMove

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces version 3.5 and p:schedule Control

I'm getting wrong date on event "eventMove".

My code fragment is as follows

Inside Managed Bean Class ScheduleController

```
public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent scheduleEntryMoveEvent)
{
      Expense exp = (Expense) scheduleEntryMoveEvent.getScheduleEvent()
            .getData();
      System.out.println("Expense Date="+exp.getDate())
}
```

and Expense class is as follows
    import java.util.Date;

```
public class Expense
{
    private Date date;
    public Date getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

For storing an expense in schedule

```
   public ScheduleController()
   {
         allExpenses = expensePeer.getList();
         for (Expense expense : allExpenses)
         {
                  eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent(expense
                .getDescription(), expense.getDate(), expense.getDate(),
                expense));
         }
   }
```

When I click on 15 August and moving schedule event (expense in my case) X to 16 August ,output is 17 August  and expected output is 16 August.

Some other moves are following

Move from      15 to 14 ,expected 14 ,getting 13

Move from 13 to 10 , expected 10, getting 7

Move from 7 to 12, expected 12, getting 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this before updating Date

```
   public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent scheduleEntryMoveEvent)
   {
      Expense exp = (Expense) scheduleEntryMoveEvent.getScheduleEvent()
        .getData();
      System.out.println("Expense Date Before="+exp.getDate())
      java.util.Calendar newCal = new GregorianCalendar();
      newCal.setTime(exp.getDate());
      newCal.add(Calendar.DATE, (-1 * scheduleEntryMoveEvent.getDayDelta()));
      newCal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, (-1 * scheduleEntryMoveEvent.getMinuteDelta()));
      exp.setDate(newCal.getTime());
      System.out.println("Expense Date After="+exp.getDate());
   }
```

Comment: Fine , now its working , but does anyone have idea why it is giving wrong date? Is it a feature or bug?